# Openframeworks graph generator

Tags: graph, openframeworks

I am trying to do a project in code blocks using openframeworks to create graphs. I have seen some tutorials regarding openframeworks graphics but couldn't able to draw a graph based on user defined input values. Can anyone suggest what are the functions here related to graphs?

P.S: Is "ofxPlotter" the right function for this?

I have used "ofDrawLine" function but it only draws line between two points. I want a function in which user puts values and a graph is built based on multiple lines.

Furthermore, what is the right link of downloading openFrameworks for code blocks? As I am unable to find any tutorial regarding openFrameworks setup for code blocks.

Comment: This feels rather broad at present. What code do you have do far? Do you have anything that plots any output already? What docs are you looking at, please add a hyperlink to your question. Have you tried `ofxPlotter`? Failing that, could you use `ofDrawLine` to draw your own graph?

Answer (score 0):

[ofxPlotter](https://github.com/yeswecan/ofxPlotter) is a good option. But I think you need to get more familiar with OpenFrameworks by understanding how basic shapes and graphics work.
I would recommend you to play with the [Graphic Example](https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/tree/master/examples/graphics/graphicsExample).

Since version 0.8.4 OpenFrameworks has [removed the support to Code Blocks](https://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/upgrade-problems-and-why-code-blocks-tutorial-removed/23713/3).
Indeed you could download [an older version](http://openframeworks.cc/download/older/), I would recommend trying the newest version choosing the [available options to download](http://openframeworks.cc/download/).